# How to implement image swipe for Blackberry 5.0 and later OS devices?

Tags: blackberry, touch, gesture

I need to develop swipe functionality in an application. For that, i have added five bitmapfields in five different verticalfield managers and these five verticalfield managers have been added in a horizontalfield manager with Horizontal Scroll property and then I tried to implement swipe functionality using Touch Event. Below code is working for Blackberry 5.0 OS devices but its not working in Blackberry 6.0 and later OS devices.

```java
    protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message)
    {

        try{
            int x = message.getX(1);
            int y = message.getY(1);       

            int eventCode = message.getEvent();  
            if(eventCode == TouchEvent.DOWN)
            {
                Dx=x; 
                Dy=y;
            }         
            else if(eventCode == TouchEvent.UP)
            {      

                Ux=x;
                Uy=y;

                disX=  Dx-Ux;
                disY=  Dy-Uy;

                if(disX > (Display.getWidth()/3)  && this.index<6)
                {

                    if(this.index<5)
                        this.index++;
                    vfmImage[this.index].setFocus();
                    System.out.println("disX :"+disX +" differnt :"+(Display.getWidth()/3)+" Index :"+this.index);

                }

                else if(disX < Display.getWidth() -(Display.getWidth() + Display.getWidth()/3)  && index>0)
                {

                    if(this.index>0)
                        this.index--;
                    vfmImage[this.index].setFocus();
                    System.out.println("disX :"+disX +"differnt :"+(Display.getWidth() -(Display.getWidth() + Display.getWidth()/3))+" Index :"+this.index);

                }
                else
                {
                    if(index==0)
                    {
                        vfmImage[1].setFocus();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        vfmImage[this.index-1].setFocus();
                    }

                    vfmImage[this.index].setFocus();

                }

            }  

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Dialog.alert("catch");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return super.touchEvent(message);
    }
```

Thanks
Devang

Comment: is this touchEvent() method defined in your HorizontalFieldManager?

Comment: You can try PictureScrollField http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/extension/component/PictureScrollField.html